# Q.js, promises, classes and "this", what is the context?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, q

I'm completely confused about the context inside a Q promise. I don't think that's Q specific, but general with all promises. What the hell is the context of `this` inside a class?

This code uses TypeScript, everything is static now, because I basically **failed** to do anything non-static. This code works fine.

I tried to add a `private _config;` instance variable and use the `_getConfig` method to set the `_config` in the constructor. But when I used `this._config` inside the method `checkMongodbConnection`, well, it wasn't the same object as what was returned by the `_getConfig()` method. (I watched variable states in debug mode)

So I guess that `this`, inside a class, because I call the code from a Q promise, don't have the class instance context.

I'm wondering if using promises is a good idea after all, if I run into context issues the code will just be **a lot** more difficult to understand and to debug. I would appreciate to understand why and made a choice in consequence. I don't want to lost the class instance context, that's way too much tricky. I'm afraid to use a technology that will actually makes things more complicated, I prefer *callback hell* to that.

```
///<reference path='./def/defLoader.d.ts'/>    
export class App {

    /**
     * Constructor.
     * Load the config.
     * @return {}
     */
    private static _getConfig(){
        if(typeof __config !== "undefined"){
            return __config;
        }else{
            require('./../../shared/lib/globals/services');
            return configHelper.load('_serverConfig', require('./../../shared/config/_serverConfig.json').path.config, __dirname + '/../../');
        }
    }

    /**
     * Check that the mongoose connection open correctly, meaning that the mongod process is running on the host.
     * @return {Q.Promise<T>|Function}
     */
    public static checkMongodbConnection(){
        var config = App._getConfig();

        // Building promise
        var deferred: any = Q.defer();

        if(config.game.checkMongodb){
            // Retrieves the mongoose configuration file, the env doesn't matter here.
            var mongodbConfig = require('./../../shared/config/mongodb.json')['development'];

            // Try mongoose connexion
            mongoose.connect('mongodb://' + mongodbConfig.host + '/' + mongodbConfig.database);

            // Bind connexion
            var db: mongoose.Connection = mongoose.connection;

            // Get errors
            db.on('error', function(err) {
                deferred.reject('Mongodb is not running, please run the mongod process: \n' + err)
            });

            // If the connexion seems to be open
            db.once('open', function callback () {
                // Close it
                db.db.close();

                // Resolve promise
                deferred.resolve();
            });
        }else{
            deferred.resolve();
        }

        // Get back promise
        return deferred.promise;
    }

    /**
     * Check that the redis connection is open, meaning that the redis-server process is running on the host.
     * @return {Q.Promise<T>|Function}
     */
    public static checkRedisConnection(){
        var config = App._getConfig();

        // Building promise
        var deferred: any = Q.defer();

        if(config.game.checkRedis) {
            // Create the redis client to test to connexion on server
            var redisClient:any = redis.createClient();

            // Get client errors
            redisClient.on("error", function (err) {
                deferred.reject(err);
            });

            // Try applying a key
            redisClient.set("keyTest", true);

            // Now key is applied, try getting it
            redisClient.get("keyTest", function (err, reply) {
                if (err) {
                    deferred.reject("Redis is not running, please make sure to run redis before to start the server. \n" + err);
                } else {
                    deferred.resolve();
                }
            });
        }else{
            deferred.resolve();
        }

        // Get back promise
        return deferred.promise;
    }
}
```

Code that calls the class:

```
Q.fcall(App.checkRedisConnection)
    .then(App.checkMongodbConnection)
    .then(function(result) {
         // run server
    }, console.error);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The promises/A+ specification dictates explicitly that the value of `this` inside a promise chain is always undefined (strict mode) or the global object via:

> 2.2.5 onFulfilled and onRejected must be called as functions (i.e. with no this value).

Specified [here](http://promisesaplus.com/).

If you're not using a promise library like Bluebird that allows setting `this` explicitly (via `.bind`), you can still utilize TypeScript's fat arrows (also in ES6) to call something with lexical `this`.

Comment: First of all, use Bluebird instead of Q would be a good idea, thanks for pointing this out. I don't know TS fat arrow, I'm reading about it.

Comment: Fat arrows are shorter function syntax, but they also bind the 'this' value lexically.